# Empty RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY

Tags: cmake

Working on a project using CMake. This project contains an executable and a python script. These two files should be compiled/copied in the same directory at build.

I try something like :

```
add_executable( ${myTarget} ${all_c_sources} )
add_custom_command(
  TARGET ${myTarget} POST_BUILD
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy ${pythonScriptPath} ${RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY}/
)
```

The executable is well build in a default location like ${CMAKE_BINARY_DIR}/Debug but the copy of the python script failed :

```
c:\Program Files (x86)\CMake\bin\cmake.exe" -E copy C:/.../script.py /\r
```

My goal is to use CMake default behavior as mush as possible.
Is there a simple way to get the default output path ?

Thanks !

Comment: You have missed closed brace in `${RUNTIME_OUTPUT_DIRECTORY/`.

Comment: Why "at build" and not "at install" ?

Comment: Installation is not necessary for this project for now. We just want to execute the python script with the executable beside as soon as they are compiled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this:

```
add_custom_command(TARGET ${LIBRARY_NAME} POST_BUILD
  COMMAND ${CMAKE_COMMAND} -E copy_if_different
  $<TARGET_FILE:${LIBRARY_NAME}>
  $<TARGET_FILE_DIR:${CMAKE_PROJECT_NAME}>/path/to/where/module/should/be
  COMMENT "Copying file to Runtime directory: " $<TARGET_FILE:${LIBRARY_NAME}>
)
```

Adjust it to your needs.

Read about [CMake Generator Expressions](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.3/manual/cmake-generator-expressions.7.html) if you need to know more.